# Setting the "Selected" property of an ASP.NET ListItem (HTML Generic Control)

Tags: asp.net

For reasons outside my control I have a table containing input and select fields built using regular HTML with the `runat="server"` attribute (as opposed to standard ASP.NET controls).  I am trying to set a value to be selected when the page is loaded based on values being passed from the Session (again, factor outside my control).

Setting the `Selected` property of the list item does nothing and doesn't select the item in question.  How do I achieve this?

The code is basically this (names generic-ized):

```
HtmlSelect dropdownList = ((HtmlSelect)myTable.Rows[0].Cells[5].FindControl("DropdownList");
DataSet allListItems = this.GetDefaultListItems();
foreach (DataRow row in allListItems.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem(row["TextField"].ToString(), row["ValueField"].ToString());
    if (li.Text == selectedListItemText)
    {
        li.Selected = true;
    }
    dropdownList.Items.Add(li);
}
```

the `Select` portion doesn't work, although it gets executed on the proper item.  Should this code be called in a specific event?  I believe it's being called in Page_Load; should it be called in Pre_Render instead?

**EDIT 03/09/2011**: Well, I don't know how I fixed it but it's working now.  So... yeah.

Comment: This should work. What does dropdownList.SelectedIndex return after you executed this code? Where in Page_Load are you calling this? Where does this Session-value gets its value from and are you calling this only if !IsPostback?

Comment: The session is populated on another page which redirects to the one the above code is on; I am calling a method that populates a bunch of controls based on the values in the session, if a particular session variable is set (to make a long story short the page is standalone but we are enabling some pieces of data to be filled in on another page first and the user is taken to this page to finish their data entry).  Also, after I execute that code, SelectedIndex is 0 on the HtmlSelect.

Comment: My guess (in my hastily composed answer below) is that the Selected property of an unbound list item won't get picked up when it's added to a list (e.g. it will not cause the list's current `SelectedIndex` value to be changed).

Comment: Hmm, actually the source code for `HtmlSelect` refutes this, it simply returns the first element where `Selected`=true.

Comment: EDIT I spoke too soon, it's selecting only the first value, not the value that I'm saying is selected.

Comment: @Wayne: as i have asked you above(wondered me because it worked for me) ;)

Comment: @Wayne: so why do you thought that it's working now when the selectedIndex is still 0? What has changed when doing this only if !IsPostback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (DataRow row in allListItems.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem(row["TextField"].ToString(), row["ValueField"].ToString());
    dropdownList.Items.Add(li);    
    if (li.Text == selectedListItemText)
    {
        dropdownList.SelectedIndex = dropdownList.Items.Count-1;
    }
}
```

**edit**

Source for get SelectedIndex in HtmlSelect:

```
get {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      if (this.Items[i].Selected)
      {
          return i;
      }
    }
 }
...

set {
...
   if (value >= 0)
  {
      this.Items[value].Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Meaning... it should be functionally identical to set the Selected property for a single ListItem at any time, so my suggestion is functionally identical to the original.

So, suspect: data problem, e.g. more than one item marked as selected? Lifecycle problem (created control at wrong time?)

Comment: I think you mean `dropdownList.SelectedIndex = dropdownList.Count - 1;`

Comment: I'm assuming you mean dropdownList.Items.Count - 1 since there's no "Count" property on an HtmlSelect.

Comment: Argh, busted again! Fixed. Thanks. `throw new NotProofreadingException()`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't solve the issue but it was helpful nonetheless so you get an upvote.

Comment: Yeah, see my comment on your question. Should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working test-code, now, what`s the difference to yours?

aspx:

```
<table id="myTable" runat="server">
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Dropdown:</td><td><select id="DropdownList" runat="server"></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codebehind:

```
private string selectedListItemText {
    get {
        if (Session("selectedListItemText") == null) {
            Session("selectedListItemText") = "7. row";
        }
        return Session("selectedListItemText").ToString;
    }
    set { Session("selectedListItemText") = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        HtmlSelect dropdownList = (HtmlSelect)myTable.Rows(0).Cells(5).FindControl("DropdownList");
        DataSet allListItems = this.GetDefaultListItems();
        foreach (DataRow row in allListItems.Tables[0].Rows) {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(row["TextField"].ToString(), row["ValueField"].ToString());
            if (li.Text == selectedListItemText) {
                li.Selected = true;
            }
            dropdownList.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
}

private DataSet GetDefaultListItems()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(tbl);
    tbl.Columns.Add("ValueField");
    tbl.Columns.Add("TextField");

    for (Int32 i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
        row["ValueField"] = i;
        row["TextField"] = i + ". row";
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

[converted from VB.Net to C#]

Comment: That's the issue; there isn't a difference (except the names, obviously). The only difference is that instead of a Session, the value that I'm checking to determine if an item is selected is from a DataRow.  The line is being called (I've checked it via the Debugger) but it's not actually being set when the page loads (it defaults to an empty, blank row, not even the 1st item in the list)